# How can redirect to my iOS application from instagram app after share

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, instagram

I written the below code for sharing an image through instagram. It is working fine but my problem is i want to redirect to my application after sharing is done.

```
 -(void)instaGramWallPost
{
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) //check for App is install or not
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height));
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); //convert image into .png format.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];//create instance of NSFileManager
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insta.igo"]]; //add our image to the path
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil]; //finally save the path (image)
    NSLog(@"image saved");

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSString *fileNameToSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/insta.igo"];
    NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameToSave];
    NSLog(@"jpg path %@",jpgPath);
    NSString *newJpgPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@",jpgPath];
    NSLog(@"with File path %@",newJpgPath);
    NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:newJpgPath];
    NSLog(@"url Path %@",igImageHookFile);

    self.documentController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    self.documentController = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
    self.documentController=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
    [self.documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView: self.view animated:YES];
}
else
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Please install instagram and try again" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
}
}

-(UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL*) fileURL usingDelegate: (id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate      {

UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;
return interactionController;
}
```

and i am calling instagramWallPost method when ever required.I am able to share it is working fine. But my problem is after that i want to redirect to my application. How can i do this or is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible due to Instagram's isolated sharing mechanism; all you can do is use the built-in share controller to send your image to Instagram, and then it's up to the user whether they switch back to your app or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to redirect into your own application after posting images / videos on Instagram. Because there is no such SDK or API provided by Instagram that redirects into your app after posting something on it. User have to manually open the application after doing this operation.